# Responsive Images - Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am using the bootstrap framework, I am looking to have 3 images as shown in the jsfiddle link below act in a responsive manor when the window size changes/monitor size is too small to display the full sized images. It is important the images remain on the same line (if possible) with no spacing in between.

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/660x160.png"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
```

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/mztyoy7q/

Comment: add a class to this tags `class="img-responsive"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a class to the image tags, and don't forget to add the bootstrap! 
Just make sure you link the bootstrap, and you can use this free CDN:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

and add the class

```
class="img-responsive"
```

to your img tags.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mztyoy7q/1/)

**EDIT:** If you want the images on the same line, just create a couple divs.
first, create a parent div,

```
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; height:auto; background-color:#ff0000;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/660x160.png">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
</div>
```

This `div` element will be red with 100% width, and automatically resizing height.
Then add divs between every image with the style `float:left;` like so:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; height:auto;background-color:#ff0000;">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/660x160.png">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mztyoy7q/5/) If this works, please let me know!

Comment: Hello mate, thanks for the help. I already tried this but as you can see each image is on a separate line, I would like all three of them to be on the same line if possible, thanks.

Comment: Add a wrapping div. Let me figure it out so I can get you the correct jsfiddle.

Comment: Much appreciated @InvincibleM, this has been doing my head in all evening. Take your time, thanks again!

Comment: There you go @MrBlobby

Comment: That is perfect InvincibleM, thank you so much. One last thing. How would I go about centering the contents of the div as seen in this screenshot; https://i.gyazo.com/c7ab68a828a3b7f84f6d5b37f905c4cf.png.

Comment: I cant figure it out exactly. Sorry

Comment: Its ok, the first part is exactly as needed. Just need the three images to center, let me know if you solve it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your images to some grid/columns (e.g. `.col-*`) and make these images to fill 100% of available space (`.img-responsive`). This is a clean and elegant way to do it, using just bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/660x160.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x160.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvv89L1j/1/

About removing spaces, the easiest way would be just add your own styles to overwrite padding that bootstrap adds. You need to set `padding-left` and `padding-right` to `0` for columns (you can see where that padding comes from in browser inspector, of course).